# When getting ringtone title for "Hangout Message", I get 11?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the name of an alarm that the user just selected. It works for ALMOST every alarm I've tested. So far there's only one exception: Hangout Message. I pick an alarm with this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select ringtone for notifications:");
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
if (alarm.getSound() != null) {
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, alarm.getSound());
} else {
    Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, alert);
}
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
startActivityForResult(intent, alarm.getID());
```

and my `onActivityResponse`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int id, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri ringtone = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
        if (id != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Alarms.size(); i++) {
                Alarm alarm = Alarms.get(i);
                if (alarm.getID() == id) {
                    alarm.setSound(ringtone);
                    alarm.UpdateView();
                    DB.SaveAlarm(alarm);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a pretty simple way to get ringtone names from a URI:

```
Ringtone tone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this.Con, this.Sound);
AlarmSound.setText(tone.getTitle(this.Con).toUpperCase());
```

`this.Con` is a context, generally an `Activity`, potentially a `Service`. The `Alarm` class is my own class. `this.Sound` is a URI for a ringtone. For every other alarm that's not Hangout Message, this works great and gives me the correct ringtone name. For Hangout Message, I get `11` and no errors. The URI is `content://media/external/audio/media/11` so I see where it got `11` from, but I want to translate that to its proper name. I don't want to hard code a special case for it.

How can I get Hangout Message from this URI?

I do want to note that in my code where I set the Existing URI, if Hangout Message is the existing sound, it will pre-select it properly just like any other ringtone. The ringtone selector does show it's name properly and the app does play the sound correctly when the time comes.

EDIT: I've found where the stock Android DeskClock app gets the title name [here (line 1356)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.4.2_r1/com/android/deskclock/AlarmClockFragment.java?av=f):

```
private String getRingToneTitle(Uri uri) {
    // Try the cache first
    String title = mRingtoneTitleCache.getString(uri.toString());
    if (title == null) {
        // This is slow because a media player is created during Ringtone object creation.
        Ringtone ringTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, uri);
        title = ringTone.getTitle(mContext);
        if (title != null) {
            mRingtoneTitleCache.putString(uri.toString(), title);
        }
    }
    return title;
}
```

Aside from the caching, it's not doing anything different than I am. This leads me to believe that maybe I'm creating the problem elsewhere but I have no clue what else could be impacting this. Could rooting or the Xposed framework have this specific a side affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'd actually read the logs, I could have figured this out a long time ago.

Because it's a ringtone provided by another app, I need a new permission to get info about it. I needed `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and after adding it, it worked perfectly.