# Android permission denied when reading /proc/self/exe from non-main thread

Tags: java, android, linux, system

I'm trying to get the canonical path of /proc/self/exe. When I do this on the Main Thread it works, when I do this on an different thread it crashes with an IOException: "Permission denied":

```
                   DBG  E  Thread: main
                        E  Path: /system/bin/app_process32
                        E  Thread: Thread-21656
            System.err  W  java.io.IOException: Permission denied
                        W      at java.io.File.canonicalizePath(Native Method)
                        W      at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:414)
                        W      at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:428)
                        W      at com.quanturium.testbugprocselfexe.MyActivity.getPathOfExecutable(MyActivity.java:36)
                        W      at com.quanturium.testbugprocselfexe.MyActivity.access$000(MyActivity.java:12)
                        W      at com.quanturium.testbugprocselfexe.MyActivity$1.run(MyActivity.java:26)
                        W      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getPathOfExecutable(); // Works as expected

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run ()
        {
            getPathOfExecutable(); // Trigger the IOException: Permission denied
        }
    }).start();
}

private void getPathOfExecutable()
{
    try
    {
        Log.e("DBG", "Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Log.e("DBG", "Path: " + new File("/proc/self/exe").getCanonicalFile().getPath());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This error only happens when debuggable is configured to false in the build.gradle file

Code to try it out: https://github.com/quanturium/TestBugProcSelfExe

Is this a bug or an intended behavior? What would be a workaround to get the path of the current executable?

Comment: Anytime I had issues with permissions, albeit different permissions, the logcat mentioned exactly which permission was missing just before the exception was printed. What is in the 10 or so lines above the exception?

Comment: No, this is the whole error

Comment: It might be the whole error but when I was having [issues reading Alarm names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794486/when-getting-ringtone-title-for-hangout-message-i-get-11), there was a different log entry separate from the error that told me I needed the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: Trust me, this is everything there is to see.

Comment: The `canonicalizePath()` method, modulo a couple of wrappers, is this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/lollipop-release/luni/src/main/native/canonicalize_path.cpp (assuming you're on Android 5.0). My guess would be the `readlink()` is failing for some reason ("self" is a symlink), though I can't figure out why it would.

Comment: Of what use do you expect this information to actually be?

Comment: I'm using this inside a C library to get the path to an executable. This java code was just an example and triggers the same output (IO Exception). I was wondering why it happens on a different thread but not on the main thread.

Comment: Have you made any progress,? This question has piqued my curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Does the code block? If it doesn't, there should be no ramifications of running it in the main thread. You can, however, do that from another thread, with:

```
Context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    getPathOfExecutable();
});
```

This is the cleanest work around I can think of, short of editing the permissions of your file (that you can't get the path of without running your code on the main thread anyways) because you have r/w privileges on /proc/self/exe.

This is very weird, and I am still researching the permission differences in different threads on android.

If you can get it working in the main thread, my opinion would be to just do it in the main thread, and not worry much about optimization, as the performance is no different on different threads.

Comment: Yes this code work but is executed on the main thread. As suspected canRead() returns true on the main thread and false on an other thread.

Comment: Hmm, what is the output of `ls -al /process/self/exe`? Also the output of the same command on the file the link points to?

Comment: It is also indeed ran on the main thread with this code (that's why I asked if it blocked). I'm unsure why permissions differ by thread, so this might be the best approach.

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx u0_a416  u0_a416           2015-02-20 16:36 exe -> /system/bin/toolbox

Not sure I understand your second question.

Comment: The permissions on /proc/self/exe seem good. Notice that /proc/self/exe is a link to /system/bin/toolbox? What is the output of `ls -al /system/bin/toolbox`?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x root     shell      152156 1970-04-06 02:56 toolbox. Works on both thread.

Comment: No, only from the main thread. I'm not really interested in toolbox anyway. I want to use /proc/self/exe to detect the path of my executable, a library written in C (not that it really matters for the question...)

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood. You could `readlink /proc/self/exe` but that doesn't seem very elegant. Is there a reason you can't use /proc/self/exe itself as the path to your executable?

Comment: /proc/self points to the process itself; using a command line tool on it is not particularly informative as then you will be getting information about that tool's process, not your app's.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I was unaware of the special case of /proc/self, and am currently searching a (better) solution to get the target of a symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

> What would be a workaround to get the path of the current executable?

Since every Android app is forked from Zygote, which is the first Java vm process when the virtual machine created by `/system/bin/app_process` at system booting.

If you try to read the `/proc/self/exe` from your Android app, the actual executable will be `/system/bin/app_process`. Even if you read this outside of your app's main thread, the result is the same and it wouldn't have the permission error in theory.

The question you asked is a kind of weird problem, I have tested with the following code on Android 2.3.3 and worked fine.

```
new Thread() {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, new File("/proc/self/exe").getCanonicalFile().getPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}.start();
```

Comment: I want to read this as a command line in a JNI library using native C. The same error occurs in java (IO permission denied) and I decided to put the java one for simplification. Yes it works on android 2.3. Someone suggested SE Linux might be the cause.